# How to add serializers.RelatedField() to Meta class fields in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, serialization

I have a simple API for a football game. I am using Django 2.0 and Django REST framework. I have these two models for `Team` and `Player`

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    budget = models.FloatField(default=100.0) # Millions? 114.53 M

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    competitions = models.ManyToManyField(Season)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    inMarket = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lastInMarket = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='team')
```

As far as I've read, this is the properly way of defining OneToMany relations, this is, a `Team` has many `Players`. Now, in the other hand, I want to display an `APIView` for a concrete team to show all the information of the team including the information of players. I have these two `Serializers`:

```
class PlayersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'age', 'position', 'team')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass


class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    players = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('name', 'user', 'competitions')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Team.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.players = validated_data
        return instance
```

This is the best way I've found so far of *retrieving* the players of the team. However, I'm not sure if it is the right way. Anyway, I can't add `players` to `fields` because `Team` model has no players attribute (An exception is raised). How could I fix this somehow? I'm kind of lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really easy. You can use your `related_name` which you defined in your model (`team`). It would be better rename this field to `players`. You can define Serializer for Player as you did and then in the field you add `related_name`. In your case `team` (or `players`). And then in Team serializer you add serializer for players (you can add players if you define them as `related_name`).

In `models.py`:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    inMarket = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lastInMarket = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='players')
```

In the `serializers.py`:

```
class PlayersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # you don't need RelatedField to Team because players will be under the team
    team = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'age', 'position', 'team')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    players = PlayerSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('name', 'user', 'competitions', 'players')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Team.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.players = validated_data
        return instance
```

Send a comment if you will have some problem with implementation and tell me if it is working as you expect.

Comment: I think you you also want `source='player_set'` when defining `players` in `TeamSerializer`.

Comment: thank you, that worked perfect for me. As you might guess, I was confused with the attribute `related_name`, since it was defined in `Player` model

Comment: Glad to help. I remember that I was confused when I used this as well